# multipart Identifier cound not be bound in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I am creating a procedure. I have an xml file from which i want to update data in my tables. I am creating a procedure to updata data in table.
This is my procedure
Hi,I am creating a procedure. I have an xml file from which i want to update data in my tables. I am creating a procedure to updata data in table.
This is my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateAssetsAvailability]

@assetAvailxml xml

   BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH AssetAvail AS
(
    SELECT
        uniqueKey.value('AssetId[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as assetid,
        uniqueKey.value('AvailabilityStatus[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as 
         availabilityStatus,
        uniqueKey.value('SourceSystemCode[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as sscode
    FROM
        @assetAvailxml.nodes('/Assets/asset') as Keys(uniqueKey)
)

    Update dbo.Asset set Availability=(Select Id from dbo.AssetStatus where 
    Code=AssetAvail.availabilityStatus) 
    where AssetId=assetid AND SourceSystem=(Select Id from dbo.SourceSystem 
    where code=AssetAvail.sscode)

     END;
```

This is my XML File

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Assets>
      <asset>
      <AssetId>64_assetid</AssetId>
      <AvailabilityStatus>Partial</AvailabilityStatus>
      <SourceSystemCode>GE_Cares</SourceSystemCode>
      </asset>
      <asset>
      <AssetId>81_assetid</AssetId>
      <AvailabilityStatus>Partial</AvailabilityStatus>
      <SourceSystemCode>GE_Cares</SourceSystemCode>
      </asset>
      <asset>
    <AssetId>50_assetid</AssetId>
     <AvailabilityStatus>Down</AvailabilityStatus>
    <SourceSystemCode>GE_Cares</SourceSystemCode>
    </asset>
       <asset>
      <AssetId>1-21B4-4787</AssetId>
      <AvailabilityStatus>Up</AvailabilityStatus>
      <SourceSystemCode>SIEBEL</SourceSystemCode>
       </asset>
     </Assets>
     </xml>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576160/unknown-provider-ngdialogprovider)

Comment: did you define ng-dialog in your module like this var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog']);

Comment: I ddid that n m getting this error now [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngDialog' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include ngDialog.js and ngDialog.css to your project?

such as, add following line：
`<script src="js/ngDialog.js"></script>
<link href="/css/ngDialog.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: I added ng-Dialog.js and ng-Dialog.min.js into my bower components

Comment: I added but still same error m getting   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider <- ngDialog <- userDetailController

Comment: make true the ngDialog file path you add to your file is right?